# How can i change my navbar in my wordpress site?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website with the cloudpress theme, in the style.css I have this piece of code for the symbol that in the navbar is at the active page of the website, i have edited the zone from `content: '';` to `display: block;` because my objective is to get a sort of underlining of the page name; somebody can help me?

If you want to see with this code how it is here is the website: https://breezymodels.rf.gd/

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar5 .nav .nav-item .nav-link {
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
    }
    .navbar5.navbar {padding-bottom: 0;padding-top: 0;}
    .navbar5 .header-module {padding: 10px 15px; float: right;}
    .navbar5.navbar .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        width: auto;
        padding: 1px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, as the :after element has no content, "width: auto" will return 0. You have to specify the desired dimensions in pixels or percentage, for example.

So, if you want some sort of decoration which just underlines a part of the name, you could do:

```
.navbar5.navbar .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}
```

Or, if you want the whole name underlined, then:

```
.navbar5.navbar .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px); /*full width excluding padding*/
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a simple white line underneath the active menu element?

This can simply be done with:

```
.nav-item.active {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

I would also advise to create a new line of style rules for only the element you are targeting, right now you are targeting multiple elements which i assume was listed as is because they shared the same styling.

Also, any declerations you are doing in the block:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   ///
}
```

Will only be in effect when the window size is larger then 992px.